# grails error: return type of getGrailsApplication() is incompatible

Tags: grails-2.0, grails-3.1

we are upgrading a grails 2.2.5 application to grails 3.1 and have an interesting error.  What does this mean and how should it be resolved?

```
/myapp/grails-app/controllers/myapp/admin/AdminProjectController.groovy: -1: 
The return type of java.lang.Object getGrailsApplication() in myapp.admin.AdminProjectController is incompatible with grails.core.GrailsApplication in grails.web.api.WebAttributes
. At [-1:-1]  @ line -1, column -1.
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks to burtbeckwith on this [issue](https://github.com/gpc/export/issues/15#issuecomment-231203234).

"Controllers in Grails 2 and Grails 3 already have an implicit dependency injection for GrailsApplication, so you're adding a second. In Grails 2 it's not typed (def grailsApplication) but in Grails 3 it is typed (GrailsApplication grailsApplication), so you've effectively added an override, but with a less specific return type which is invalid. Just delete your def grailsApplication and use the one that's already there."

If you just remove `def grailsApplication` from all controllers it will be fixed.